# Can I show contributors to my website a Google Analytics report of the visitors to their posts?

Tags: google-analytics, users, visitors, post

I have a website where specific users can post different types of content.  I want each user to be able to know how many visits each of their posts got.

So I thought about linking Google Analytics visitors counter for each link (post) with the user (post writer) control panel, So the user can know how many visitors his post got from his control panel. How can I do that?

My website is built with HTML & Bootstrap.